# Error on submitting data if multiple users logged in to the system on server

Tags: asp.net

I have developed an application in Asp.Net 3.5. In this, I have used 4-tier architecture.

### Server Detail

Application hosted on Windows Server 2008 64bit OS with IIS 7. Server is having 32GB of RAM, and 200GB of hard drive.

Both publish Application and database hosted on same server.

### Problem

I have one Review form where in I am trying to submit the review of Employee.

When single user logging in to the application on web server, application is working fine. User is able to submit their reviews. But as soon as it increases to more than one, it creates problem. Let's say, suppose more than one user is clicking on Submit button at a time to submit Review then only one employees record is storing on database rest all users data are not storing, but all Users are getting a message saying "Submitted Successfully".

Also I checked the error in Event Log, and I am getting a message like below.

> Event code: 3005  Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
>   Event time: 3/6/2013 11:53:37 AM  Event time (UTC): 3/6/2013 6:23:37
>   AM  Event ID: e417857a86074b16bbf05bce818a5b0d  Event sequence: 11 
>   Event occurrence: 1  Event detail code: 0
>
> Application information:  Application domain:
>   /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/spmstest-2-130070176529122850  Trust level: Full 
>   Application Virtual Path: /spmstest  Application Path:
>   C:\hrpmsapp\PMSPublished Test\  Machine name: INDW00029
>
> Process information:  Process ID: 9320  Process name: w3wp.exe 
>   Account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool
>
> Exception information:  Exception type: NullReferenceException 
>   Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.
>
> Request information:  Request URL:  Request path:  User host address: 
>   User:  Is authenticated: False  Authentication Type:  Thread account
>   name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool
>
> Thread information:  Thread ID: 10  Thread account name: IIS
>   APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool  Is impersonating: False  Stack trace: at
>   ASP.global_asax.Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>
> Custom event details:

Please find the sample code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using PMS.BO;
using PMS.BAL;
using System.Data.OleDb;

public partial class Reviews_DevelopmentReview : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ClsUtility cUtil = new ClsUtility();
    ClsDevRevBAL DevRevBAL = new ClsDevRevBAL();
    ClsDevRevBO DevRevBO = new ClsDevRevBO();
    ClsObjectiveBAL ObjBAL = new ClsObjectiveBAL();
    ClsMailSetBO MailSetBO = new ClsMailSetBO();
    ClsMailSetBAL MailSetBAL = new ClsMailSetBAL();

    static DataSet dsDevRevGridHead;
    static DataTable dtDataForMail;
    static int DevRevCode = 0;
    int EmpRating = 0; int MgrRating = 0;
    int result;
    static int StatusCode;
    static bool isFiveRatingApplicable = false;
    static string companyId = string.Empty;

    static string JobRoleId = string.Empty;
    static string EmpCode = string.Empty;
    static int loginEmpCode;
    static string LoginType = string.Empty;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["UserID"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("../Default.aspx?Session=expired");
        }
        LoginAuthentication loginAuth = new LoginAuthentication();
        LoginVariables loginVar = loginAuth.getSession();

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            companyId = loginVar.CompanyId;

            if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
            {
                if (Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString() != null)
                {
                    dtDataForMail = cUtil.GetEmpDetail(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString()));
                    EmpCode = Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString();
                    loginEmpCode = int.Parse(loginVar.EmployeeID);
                    LoginType = "Manager";
                }
                isFiveRatingApplicable = cUtil.GetIsFiveRatingApplicable(EmpCode);

                StatusCode = DevRevBAL.GetStatusCode(EmpCode);
                switch (StatusCode)
                {
                    case 2:
                        DisableControls();
                        btnSubmitLater.Visible = false;
                        btnSubmit.Visible = false;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        DisableControls();
                        btnSubmitLater.Visible = false;
                        btnSubmit.Visible = false;
                        btnFinalize.Visible = true;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        DisableControls();
                        btnSubmitLater.Visible = false;
                        btnSubmit.Visible = false;
                        btnFinalize.Enabled = false;
                        if (companyId == "0")
                        {
                            btnFinalize.Visible = true;
                            btnFinalize.Enabled = true;
                            txtHrComment.Enabled = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        DisableControls();
                        btnSubmitLater.Visible = false;
                        btnSubmit.Visible = false;
                        btnFinalize.Enabled = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                EmpCode = loginVar.EmployeeID;
                loginEmpCode = int.Parse(loginVar.EmployeeID);
                LoginType = "Employee";
                isFiveRatingApplicable = cUtil.GetIsFiveRatingApplicable(EmpCode);
                StatusCode = DevRevBAL.GetStatusCode(EmpCode);
                switch (StatusCode)
                {
                    case 1:
                        btnSubmit.Visible = false;
                        btnSubmitLater.Visible = false;
                        btnFinalize.Visible = false;
                        txtEmpAreaForSkill.ReadOnly = true;
                        txtEmpAreaForDev.ReadOnly = true;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        btnSubmit.Visible = false;
                        btnSubmitLater.Visible = false;
                        btnFinalize.Visible = true;
                        txtEmpAreaForSkill.ReadOnly = true;
                        txtEmpAreaForDev.ReadOnly = true;
                        txtEmployeeComment.ReadOnly = false;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        btnSubmit.Visible = false;
                        btnSubmitLater.Visible = false;
                        btnFinalize.Enabled = false;
                        txtEmpAreaForSkill.ReadOnly = true;
                        txtEmpAreaForDev.ReadOnly = true;
                        txtEmployeeComment.ReadOnly = true;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        DisableControls();
                        btnSubmitLater.Visible = false;
                        btnSubmit.Visible = false;
                        btnFinalize.Enabled = false;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        DisableControls();
                        btnSubmitLater.Visible = false;
                        btnSubmit.Visible = false;
                        btnFinalize.Enabled = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            DataTable dtData = cUtil.GetEmpDetail(int.Parse(EmpCode));
            txtEmployee.Text = dtData.Rows[0]["EmpName"].ToString();
            txtBranch.Text = dtData.Rows[0]["Branch"].ToString();
            txtDesignation.Text = dtData.Rows[0]["Designation"].ToString();
            txtManager.Text = dtData.Rows[0]["Approver"].ToString();
            JobRoleId = dtData.Rows[0]["JobRoleId"].ToString();

            if (dtData.Rows[0]["Status"].ToString() != "True")
            {
                Menu1.Items.Add(new MenuItem { ImageUrl = "../Images/selectedtab1.png", Value = "0", Text = "" });
                Menu1.Items.Add(new MenuItem { ImageUrl = "../Images/unselectedtab2.png", Value = "1", Text = "" });
                Menu1.Items.Add(new MenuItem { ImageUrl = "../Images/unselectedtab4.png", Value = "3", Text = "" });
            }
            else
            {
                Menu1.Items.Add(new MenuItem { ImageUrl = "../Images/selectedtab1.png", Value = "0", Text = "" });
                Menu1.Items.Add(new MenuItem { ImageUrl = "../Images/unselectedtab2.png", Value = "1", Text = "" });
                Menu1.Items.Add(new MenuItem { ImageUrl = "../Images/unselectedtab3.png", Value = "2", Text = "" });
                Menu1.Items.Add(new MenuItem { ImageUrl = "../Images/unselectedtab4.png", Value = "3", Text = "" });
            }
            Menu1.Items[0].Selected = true;
            FillDevRevGridView();
            FillTrainingListBox();

            if (isFiveRatingApplicable == true)
            {
                // For Competencies Section
                trRatingInstruction.Visible = false;

                // For Development Actions Section
                tblForFiveRating1.Visible = true;

                // For Development Targets Section
                lblDomesticMob.Visible = true;
                rdDomMobStatus.Visible = true;
                tblForFiveRating2.Visible = true;

                // For Comments Section
                lblHrComment.Visible = true;
                txtHrComment.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        EnableDisableControls();
    }
```

Comment: Are there any static objects that could cause the problem? Can you reproduce it, when you debug your app?

Comment: Yes, in my code I have static objects like string, int, DataTable, and DataSet too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you use a static object which needs not to be unique to each user?

The scope of a static variable is application wide and shared among all users!

So, that more than one user tries to access the same DataTable or a DataSet instance seems a bit strange to me

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution helped me. I removed static fields and now it started working...